# trying to pass file name from aspx page to console.exe

Tags: c#, textbox, console, argument-passing

i want to pass the value of a lable or textbox in an aspx page to a console.exe application
such that the if the value is sample.doc it changes to that.

i am calling from the aspx page with

```
   string f = TextBox1.Text;

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/DocUpload/ConsoleApplication1.exe", f);
```

i have tried converting to string then using the string vatiable inplace of sample.doc but no luck

object FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ExecutableFileInfo.DirectoryName, "sample.doc");

any help or ideas will be welcomed.
thank u

Comment: What is the value of the textbox? Is it supposed to be a file on disk? If so, what folder? What error do you get?

Comment: You should name your textbox.

Comment: the value of the textbox is the name of the file i wish to process and anypoint in time 

the console app starts displays the file name and crashes

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I  use to start processes from calling applications.  Since you are calling it from a web-app you are going to need to make sure you have appropriate permissions.

```
        Process         proc                = new Process();
        StringBuilder   sb                  = new StringBuilder();
        string[]        aTarget             = target.Split(PATH_SEPERATOR); 
        string          errorMessage;
        string          outputMessage;

        foreach (string parm in parameters)
        {
            sb.Append(parm + " ");
        }

        proc.StartInfo.FileName                 = target;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError    = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput   = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute          = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments                = sb.ToString();

        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit
            (
                (timeout <= 0)
                ? int.MaxValue : (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout).TotalMilliseconds
            );


        errorMessage    = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        outputMessage   = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

A link to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

You'll also need to check to make sure that the account the Web application is running under has the appropriate permissions to execute the program.

Comment: When linking to MSDN, you should link to the default version, not .Net 1.1.

Comment: hey Guys thanks for the suggsetions it got me thinking more so i used this in the aspx file
 string filename = TextBox1.Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/DocUpload/ConsoleApplication1.exe", filename)

and used the code below on the console.exe
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in args)
            {
                sb.Append(s);
            }
object docFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ExecutableFileInfo.DirectoryName, sb.ToString());

thanks alot guys ur the best

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to process a file that is in a different folder.

If so, you need to pass the full path of the file, like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\DocUpload\ConsoleApplication1.exe", 
              Path.Combine(@"C:\path\to\folder", TextBox1.Text));
```

Comment: well the console app and the files are in the same folder but will try your recommendation